# Watson User Modeling service returns error "Cannot read property '0' of undefined when reading from VCAP_SERVICES

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

It seems like the Watson User Modeling service was removed from my application.  I'm getting the following error in my app.

```
2015-04-09T15:23:38.44-0400 [App/0]   ERR /home/vcap/app/lib/config.js:33
2015-04-09T15:23:38.44-0400 [App/0]   ERR                 return vcapServices["user_modeling"][0].credentials.url;
2015-04-09T15:23:38.44-0400 [App/0]   ERR                                                     ^
2015-04-09T15:23:38.44-0400 [App/0]   ERR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
2015-04-09T15:23:38.44-0400 [App/0]   ERR     at Object.watsonUrl (/home/vcap/app/lib/config.js:33:53)
2015-04-09T15:23:38.44-0400 [App/0]   ERR     at getPersonality (/home/vcap/app/lib/app.js:203:25)
2015-04-09T15:23:38.44-0400 [App/0]   ERR     at async.waterfall.personalityUser1 (/home/vcap/app/lib/app.js:278:13)
2015-04-09T15:23:38.44-0400 [App/0]   ERR     at fn (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:641:34)
2015-04-09T15:23:38.44-0400 [App/0]   ERR     at Object._onImmediate (/home/vcap/app/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:557:34)
2015-04-09T15:23:38.44-0400 [App/0]   ERR     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:345:15)
```

What happened and what do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The User Modeling service was recently renamed. It is now Personality Insights.  I fixed this by adding the new Personality Insights service to my app and updating my code for reading VCAP_SERVICES.

Instead of doing the following:

```
var VCAP_SERVICES = process.env["VCAP_SERVICES"],
    vcapServices;

if (VCAP_SERVICES) {
    vcapServices = JSON.parse(VCAP_SERVICES);
}

return vcapServices["user_modeling"][0].credentials.url;
```

Do the following instead.  Note user_modeling is related with personality_insights.

```
var VCAP_SERVICES = process.env["VCAP_SERVICES"],
    vcapServices;

if (VCAP_SERVICES) {
    vcapServices = JSON.parse(VCAP_SERVICES);
}

return vcapServices["personality_insights"][0].credentials.url;
```

Additionally the API changed a bit...  The URL is now the URL you get from `VCAP_SERVICES + /v2/profile`.  It was `VCAP_SERVICES + /api/v2/profile`

More exactly `vcapServices["personality_insights"][0].credentials.url + "/v2/profile"`.